# C++ doesn't write expected numbers into file

Tags: c++

Dears,
i am trying to export contents of below vector like below example but each time Sale price in the exporting file shows as zero

**Sale price: 1.65749e-06** amount 0.895962 timeStamp 2020/06/01 11:57:35.334211

```
void CSVWriter::appendToCSVFile(std::string fileName, std::vector<std::string> attributes)
{
    fstream fout;  // Create Object of Of stream
    ifstream fin;

    fout.open (fileName,std::ios::out | std::ios::app); // make sure file exists if not create it
    fout.close();
    fout.open (fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::app);  // Append mode
    fin.open(fileName);
    std::string concatenatedAttributes="";
    if(fin.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); ++i) {

            if(i!=attributes.size()-1)
                concatenatedAttributes+=attributes[i]+",";
            else
                concatenatedAttributes+=attributes[i];
        }
        fout << concatenatedAttributes+"\n"; // Writing data to file

    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close(); // Closing the file
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? For instance, what does the `fin.is_open()` return? What is the value of `concatenatedAttributes` at the time of attempted write?

Comment: @WhozCraig "_And fyi, You use of fin in this code is nonsense. It is blindly opened, never checked, and never used except to close._" While I agree that the use is nonsense - it is used to decide whether to write to `fout` (`if(fin.is_open())`).

Answer (score 2):

Consider opening the `fout` file as:

```
std::ofstream fout{fileName, std::ios::ate | std::ios::app}; // open for appending (create if not already exists)
```

Also, do not open the file twice (the second open makes the first obsolete).

If this still doesn't work, add a call to fout.flush() and the end.

**Edit:**

Some other notes:

- `if(fin.is_open()) {` is unnecessary:

  Instead, just write directly.
- opening the file for append should result in an implementation similar to:

  ```
  void CSVWriter::appendToCSVFile(std::string fileName,
      std::vector<std::string> attributes)
  {
      auto fout = fstream{fileName, std::ios::app|std::ios::ate};
      if(!attributes.empty())
      {
          std::copy_n(begin(attributes), attributes.size() - 1, 
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(fout, ","));
          fout << attributes.back() << "\n";
      }
  }
  ```

  This is more efficient (as you do not re-read the file in order to regenerate it, you just add a line at the end).

  By using iterator support (and std::copy), you have no need for an index variable (`i` in your code) or for an if statement within the for loop.
- unless you are launching the function on a separate thread, it is probably better to pass the arguments as const references:

  ```
  void CSVWriter::appendToCSVFile(std::string const& fileName,
      std::vector<std::string> const& attributes)
  ```